# Link web page, Facebook Like button, and Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is this possible?

- When someone clicks a Facebook Like button, he/she shares the web page URL with friends on Facebook.
- With the same click, the user also becomes a fan of the web site's Facebook fan page.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean at the same time? You want to create the button, do the action of the button, and become a fan all in one click?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if that is. With the little work of Facebook's API, I think the user has to t confirm in a popup... Not sure if it's possible. Good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) on Facebook's developer site.

This will do all the points 1 and 3 you mentioned above.  As far as point 2 goes, you will need to reference that on your facebook page.

Comment: Thanks ... to clarify, we're seeing a disparity in the people who appear as "liking" our fan page, and the people who clicked the FB Like button associated with a web page. If the Like button links back to the same page associated with the fan page, shouldn't the numbers be the same?

Comment: No, one is for "Liking" the actual page or brand if you like.  The other is to like an individual page, product, story etc.  So you're brand may be X, and you may have 3 products, A B & C.   You might have 100 people that "like" the brand X, and only 20 likes on project A, 10 "likes" on product B and zero on product C.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

While adding a Like button on your website to like you "Facebook Page" is possible (and I guess you know that), you can't use the *same* button to like multiple entities (your current page and the Facebook Page).

What you can do is:

1. Have two Like buttons, one for the current page and one for the Facebook Page
2. Place the Like button of your Facebook Page in a "*visible*" location (e.g. on top of the sidebar)
3. Capture the like event of your current page (with [`edge.create`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/))
4. **Encourage** the user to "*Become a Fan on Facebook too*" whenever they like your current page.