# Facebook Like button that posts to page wall as well?

Tags: drupal-6, facebook, fbconnect

I have a online shop. On the home page there are products, with a like button. When a person clicks on the button, it goes to their profile and it says that they liked it. However, I also want when the user clicks like, that it is posted to my BUSINESS FACEBOOK PAGE as well.

```
1. Is this possible?
2. Is this possible using the standard facebook like button?
```

I am implementing this on a site with Drupal which is using the FBConnect module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link web page, Facebook Like button, and Facebook fan page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846716/link-web-page-facebook-like-button-and-facebook-fan-page)

Comment: No. Not FAN! It must POST on the fan page that the user has liked something. NOT become a fan. Although, that would be pretty cool too, but it seems kinda like your fooling the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No

We can't do anything with that standard facebook like button. That's the way it is. However, we can achieve what you want by other means.

Since you're the owner of the business page, you can get the [access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for it, preferably with [publish_stream permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). Then you can use [edge.create](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event on the pages with the like button and detect that to [publish on your business wall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Check the links. For the access_token / authentication link, look for "Page Login".